# Asp.Net Bundle - How to raise exception when minification fails

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-bundling

I'm using Asp.Net MVC 5 and the bundling and minification system from System.Web.Optimization 1.1.0.0:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/angularLibraries").Include(
            ......
            ));
```

and then to render the Bundle:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/angularLibraries")
```

From time to time I manually check the state of my bundles by opening the corresponding url in the browser, and sometimes I find them with errors. Example:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(262,145-152): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break a
(40,297-304): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break a
 */
```

Because the bundling mechanism returns the unminified contents when the minification fails, I'm unaware of the error until I manually open that bundle in a browser.

How can I setup the Bundling system to raise an exception when minification fails so I can immediately be aware of the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution. I have created a custom class that derives from ScriptBundle and overrides the method ApplyTransforms:

```
public class CustomScriptBundle : ScriptBundle
{
    public CustomScriptBundle(string virtualPath)
        : base(virtualPath)
    {
    }

    public CustomScriptBundle(string virtualPath, string cdnPath)
        : base(virtualPath, cdnPath)
    {
    }

    public override BundleResponse ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, string bundleContent, IEnumerable<BundleFile> bundleFiles)
    {
        BundleResponse bundleResponse = base.ApplyTransforms(context, bundleContent, bundleFiles);

        if (bundleResponse.Content.StartsWith("/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents."))
            ExceptionManager.LogMessage("Minification failed for following bundle: " + context.BundleVirtualPath);

        return bundleResponse;
    }
}
```

I ended up logging a message (an receiving an email notification from Elmah) and not throwing an exception because I have minification enabled by default only on production, and the app will continue working ok anyway.

If you throw an exception, you'll see it like this:

[image]

This solution is also applicable for StyleBundle.

Comment: Did you ever resolve the problem that was causing the JS1019 error? I have the same problem but cannot find any code that breaks this rule.

Comment: @kildareflare search for the line in the unminified output (you can save the output into a file and open it in notepad++). the error message tells you the line number: "(262,145-152): run-time error JS1019....". Line 262 in this case. That's how I solve it.

Comment: Hey, yeah that's what I was doing - can't see what it is complaining about though. I'll keep digging, thanks though.